# Django App developed in Windows will not run on Linux

Tags: python, django, windows, amazon-linux-2

I have a Django application that a former colleague of mine developed. It was created in Windows, but I need to deploy it on a Linux server. The requirements.txt fails to install all requirements on the Linux server. Specifically, the mysql, mysqlconnector, and version of psutil fail to install.

I cannot find any documentation on converting a Windows Django project to be compatible with Linux. Instead, most sources say that Django apps will work on either environment interchangeably, but this does not seem to be true since I cannot install the requirements or migrate the project.

Comment: you have to be more specific .ehat's the problem? do you get an error? what's the error?

Comment: What are the errors you get ?

Answer (score -1):

Mysql connector can be tricky. You remove it from the requirements and install other packages. That connector only affects your database.

You can download a binary distribution of the connector that suits your Linux system and install.